I can't connect MongoDB with freetrial it give me error message that you don't add your enty ip in the white list
I can't connect MongoDB with free one it give me error message that you don't add your enty ip in the white list even though i try current ip or 0.0.0.0/0 ip. it doesn't work. there is nothing wrong with compatibility between npm package with mongoDB i don't know what to do.
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PAYLAŞIM KLASÖRÜ\fullstack_ecommerce_site\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:875:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PAYLAŞIM KLASÖRÜ\fullstack_ecommerce_site\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:826:11)
at async connectDB (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PAYLAŞIM KLASÖRÜ\fullstack_ecommerce_site\backend\config\db.js:4:1) {

reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'ac-l7y2b9o-shard-00-00.jzmdgy3.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-l7y2b9o-shard-00-01.jzmdgy3.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-l7y2b9o-shard-00-02.jzmdgy3.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-f0r0hg-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}

Can you expand the [ServerDescription] part?
